# Getting value as undefined while calling jquery from jsp

Tags: jquery, html

I have below defined div from which i am calling jquery:

```
<div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="30"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    var val = $(this).data('progressrel');
        alert(val);
    $(".progressbar").progressbar({
            value:val    
        });
    });
```

Getting alert as undefined.

Please help me on this as I am new to jQuery. thanks in advance

Comment: use `var val =  $(".progressbar").data('progressrel')`

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` inside `ready` function directly has no context, just use the class name :

```
var val = $('.progressbar').data('progressrel');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var val = $(".progressbar").data('progressrel');
  alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="30"></div>
```

**To get all the `divs` pregressrel you could use `.each()`:**

```js
$(function() {
  
  $(".progressbar").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).data('progressrel');
    alert(val);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="30"></div>
<div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="40"></div>
<div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="50"></div>
<div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="60"></div>
```

Comment: can u please help how to get dynamic value if i pass through "data-progressrel" inside a loop and want alert for every value it iterate

Comment: Not sure if that what you want, check the new snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `div` as follows, your reference to `this` object is not valid.

```js
 $(function() {
   var val = $("div.progressbar").data('progressrel');
   alert(val);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="30"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, it works but i have some below div's like :                               <div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="30"></div>                     <div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="40"></div>                     <div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="50"></div>                     <div class="progressbar" data-progressrel="60"></div>                             but while fetching it prints 30 only. any help would be appreciable.

Comment: @Rabindra any query?